# preg_match, what's causing the error?

Tags: php, preg-match

So i'm trying to parse some content. It looks somewthing like this.

```
## This is a Title ##

- Content will go here, so blah blah blah -
```

Now i grab that out of a table via php/mysql, and use preg_match to extract the text like so.

```
preg_match('/\##(.*?)\##/', $m_data['field'], $mod_title);
preg_match('/\-(.*?)\-/', $m_data['field'], $mod_content);
```

This works fine. However, i get a php error if either of the two have a line break in them like so.

```
## This is a 
Title ##

- Content will go here, so blah 
blah blah -
```

and this causes the following php error.

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined offset: 1

 Filename: libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code

 Line Number: 472
```

I assume the offset it's thinking of is

```
$title = $mod_title[1];                                              
$content = $mod_content[1];
```

But the array mod_content is empty when there's a line break.

I'm pretty certain it's my regular expression but i'm no guru at it, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is missing. Also, if you can paste more of your code (including the area where you load/set $content) it would help.

Comment: Don't you need to include a trailing `/s` so it matches all characters, including new lines? `preg_match('/\##(.*?)\##/s', $m_data['field'], $mod_title);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "s" modifier to your regexp:

```
preg_match('/\##(.*?)\##/s', $m_data['field'], $title);
preg_match('/\-(.*?)\-/s', $m_data['field'], $content);
```

**s (PCRE_DOTALL)**

If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

For more see: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Ok, this worked perfectly. LOL a simple missing s drove me nuts. Love it! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the preg_match doesn't match the break line.

The way to solve this would be to end with /s, instead of only /.

So it would be like this:

```
preg_match('/\##(.*?)\##/s', $m_data['field'], $title);
preg_match('/\-(.*?)\-/s', $m_data['field'], $content);
```